# Xcode call stack

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

I'm getting an exception while running iOS app in simulator

```
2013-09-16 18:03:44.346 DEV[26529:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSDecimalNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf98fc70'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x17bf012 0x1c38e7e 0x184a4bd 0x17aebbc 0x17ae94e 0x1b813 0x1c4c705 0x653920 0x6538b8 0x714671 0x714bcf 0x713d38 0x917213 0x1787afe 0x1787a3d 0x17657c2 0x1764f44 0x1764e1b 0x29db7e3 0x29db668 0x65065c 0x25c9 0x2505 0x1)
```

UPD:
Exception is caused by the following code:

```
if([self.media.idtype isEqualToString:IMAGETYPE])
```

Where idtype is `@property(retain, nonatomic) NSString *idtype;` and IMAGETYPE is `static NSString *VIDEOTYPE = @"2";`

How can I see function names instead of addresses?

Comment: Or Use Exception breakpoint for All Exceptions.

Comment: I'm using debug build I believe

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: The declaration of your properties is less important than the instantiation of those properties. Show us where you set `idtype`.

Comment: Probably you're right! Debug window with local variables says that static self.media.idtype is decimal! But how can I trace whre I set it? idtype is a property and I can not set breakpoint because setters and getters are generated by compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isEqualToString can compare two NSstrings not the other type of data that u are comparing which is NSDecimalNumber
convert your NSDecimalNumber to nsstring then do this

```
NSDecimalNumber* dec1;
NSString* str;

str = dec1.stringValue;
     NSString *str2=@"world";
                [str isEqualToString:str2];
```

Comment: Or use `[NSDecimalNumber compare:]`?

Comment: Exception happens when I'm trying to compare synthetised NSString* property and another  NSString*

Comment: @Ask Once you identify the offending line of code (e.g. with the [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html)), you should update your question with that code (and presumably the code that is setting the variables in question) because the error is clearly telling us that you're trying to use `isEqualToString` method on an object that is a `NSDecimalNumber`, not a `NSString`.

Comment: you are converting your NSDecimalNumber to NString.right?? if yes first check is that contains the . or something else.if yes then first encode that string then use

Answer (score 0):

There is some where in your code you are setting the value of  property idtype (self.media.idtype). This must be the source of the problem:

Possible Problems could be  Extracting contents from Webservice and while parsing you might be assigning it to the self.media.idtype object.